# BizTalk receiving updated/new records from SQL database

Tags: sql, adapter, biztalk

I'm using BizTalk to receive records from SQL database.
I made one SQL adapter and used select statement to retrieve all data from table.
Now I want to retrieve only new records that have been added to table after.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of "SQL Database" ?  Is it SQL Server? Can you enable change tracking?

Comment: It is local database, SQLEXPRESS 2008 R2.

Comment: [change tracking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462.aspx).  I'm not too familiar with BizTalk, so I'm not sure if this will help or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't retrieving data from a staging table (i.e. where you would delete the records after successfully retrieving them), but instead retrieving directly from a 'live' table, you will typically need a status flag column on the table to indicate whether a record has been processed or not.

It is also a usually a good idea to create a stored procedure in the source database which encapsulates the above data retrieval (i.e. retrieves a batch of data and then changes the status of records which are fetched in this batch).

Also, if you aren't doing so already, ensure that you use the [WCF-SQL adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358357/the-difference-between-wcf-sql-adapter-and-sql-adapter).